# XPath select elements between 2 certain elements

Tags: html, xpath

I have this html page:

```
<tr class="facts_label"></tr>
<tr class="facts_label"></tr>
<tr class="other_label"></tr>
<tr class="facts_label"></tr>
<tr class="facts_label"></tr>
<tr class="other_label"></tr>
<tr class="other_label"></tr>
<tr class="facts_label"></tr>
<tr class="facts_label"></tr>
<tr class="other_label"></tr>    # Select this
<tr class="other_label"></tr>    # Select this
<tr class="facts_label"></tr>
<tr class="other_label"></tr>
<tr class="other_label"></tr>
```

I want to select the tr elements with class "other_label" that are between the last 2 tr elements with class "facts_label"

I tried :

```
'//tr[@class="other_label" and (preceding-sibling::tr[@class="facts_label"][last()-1]) and (following-sibling::tr[@class="facts_label"][last()])]'
```

But this is what I got

```
<tr class="facts_label"></tr>
<tr class="facts_label"></tr>
<tr class="other_label"></tr>    # Got this
<tr class="facts_label"></tr>
<tr class="facts_label"></tr>
<tr class="other_label"></tr>    # Got this
<tr class="other_label"></tr>    # Got this
<tr class="facts_label"></tr>
<tr class="facts_label"></tr>
<tr class="other_label"></tr>    # Got this
<tr class="other_label"></tr>    # Got this
<tr class="facts_label"></tr>
<tr class="other_label"></tr>
<tr class="other_label"></tr>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Xpath*** "trick":

```
//tr[ @class='other_label' and count(following-sibling::tr[@class='facts_label'])=1 ]
```

Comment: Anyone got an explanation on how adding `count()` gets the OP's requested results?